# What locks does PostgreSQL COPY method require?

Tags: postgresql, locking, psql, pg-dump

I would like to know the locks that the COPY method may require. When I run it, I see that it uses the lock SHARE ACCESS, I would like to know if it is the only one.

I also would like to know the difference between `COPY` and `pg_dump`. Do they use the same methods under the hood? Do they need the same locks? Can they use the same transaction isolation level?

Answer (score 6):

### EDIT:

The behavior described below was recognized as a bug and [fixed](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commit;h=a9cf48a4cf0c878684a2f52a3a88e29399b2065e) in PostgreSQL v13. Now `COPY TO` will hold the lock until the end of the transaction.

---

The locks that `COPY` takes can be seen from the source of `DoCopy` in `src/backend/commands/copy.c`:

```
if (stmt->relation)
{
    LOCKMODE    lockmode = is_from ? RowExclusiveLock : AccessShareLock;
    [...]

    /* Open and lock the relation, using the appropriate lock type. */
    rel = table_openrv(stmt->relation, lockmode);

    [...]
}
[...]

/*
 * Close the relation. If reading, we can release the AccessShareLock we
 * got; if writing, we should hold the lock until end of transaction to
 * ensure that updates will be committed before lock is released.
 */
if (rel != NULL)
    table_close(rel, (is_from ? NoLock : AccessShareLock));
```

That means:

- `COPY <table> FROM` takes a `ROW EXCLUSIVE` lock, just like `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE`.
- `COPY <table> TO` takes an `ACCESS SHARE` lock, just like `SELECT`
- Different from `SELECT`, `COPY <table> TO` does not hold the lock until the end of the transaction, but releases it immediately.

This is independent of the transaction isolation level.

`pg_dump` uses `COPY` to dump the table contents, so all the above applies to pg_dump as well. `pg_dump` always uses the `REPEATABLE READ` isolation level to get a consistent snapshot of the whole database.

Comment: Are `COPY TO` and `COPY FROM` switched? I believe it's `COPY table TO STDOUT` that reads from the table, and `COPY table FROM STDIN` that writes to the table...

Comment: You are right, I mixed up the lower part of the answer. Fixed.